# "Subscript out of range" error when looping through Array to Find/Replace in a column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two lists of names on an excel sheet **`(sh1 - Column A, Column D)`**. On another excel sheet **`(sh2 - Column B)`**, I have a another list of names. I am trying to find/replace Column A names on Column B with Column D.

My full code is listed at the bottom. I am getting a "Subscript out of range" error on this line:

```
Selection.Replace What:=fndArr(i), Replacement:=rplArr(i), LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I have checked the range and it seems like the code should loop through every cell in sh2 Column B looking for Column A data and replacing it with Column D data.

I'm drawing a total blank on this. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Thank you for your help.

```
Column A       |   Column B   |  Column D
--------------------------------------------
Hugh Jackman   |  Hugh J      |  Hugh Jackman
Ronald Reagan  |  Ronald R    |  Ronald Reagan
John Adams     |  John A      |  John Adams
```

.

```
Sub CheckReplace()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim fndArr() As Variant
Dim rplArr() As Variant

Set sh1 = Sheets("CA")
Set sh2 = Sheets("FD")

''' turn off screen updating '''
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

''' Find/Replace CA '''
sh1.Activate
fndArr = sh1.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
rplArr = sh1.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

sh2.Activate
Columns("B").Select

For i = 0 To UBound(fndArr)
    Selection.EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=fndArr(i), Replacement:=rplArr(i), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next i

''' turn on screen updating '''
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

The following change in code allows it to run without throwing an error, but then it find/replaces the first values in Column A/B, e.g. Hugh Jackman Hugh J, but not Ronald Reagan, Ronald R:

```
fndArr = Array(sh1.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
rplArr = Array(sh1.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row))
```

Comment: when assigning a range directly to an array it starts at 1 not 0

Comment: So the safest method would be `For i = LBound(fndArr) To UBound(fndArr)`

Comment: I did 'For i = LBound(fndArr) To UBound(fndArr)' as you typed that up and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the value of i when the error is thrown?  Are both columns the same length?

Comment: Both columns are the same length. the Value of i = 1 when error is thrown. Check out my edit above, I changed the array variables and the code runs without throwing an error, but it only find/replaces the first value in the array.

Comment: Basically forcing the Array(sh1.range....) starts i at 0. However, it still appears to be not looping through.

Comment: They should be: `fndArr = sh1.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value` add the `.Value` to the end.  As to why it is not working, Check your data for extra spaces and other non printable characters that would be causing them not to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you equate an array to a range, you create a 1-based **2D** array, even with a single column, so:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(fndArr)
    Selection.EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=fndArr(I,1), Replacement:=rplArr(I,1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next I
```

**EDIT:** You also need to get rid of the selection stuff.  Perhaps the following (not tested)

```
'Delete these two lines
'sh2.Activate   
'Columns("B").Select

With sh2.Columns("B") 
For i = 0 To UBound(fndArr)
    .Replace What:=fndArr(I,1), Replacement:=rplArr(I,1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next i
```

Comment: @tulanejosh You also need to get rid of the Selection stuff, but that is a different issue from your error message

Comment: Why do I need to get rid of the Selection stuff?

Comment: @tulanejosh It slows down your code. It is usually the main cause of runtime errors. See especially Siddharth Rout's answer in the thread on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA Macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)  In your code in particular, you are selecting the entire column each time you go through the loop.  There is no need for that.